# BlackBerry - call time tracking application

Tags: blackberry, java-me, startup, call

hallo,

I have a common question, I hope it is ok to ask it here.

I have a project, where I should develop a small appliation for BlackBerry. I know Java ME is the platform to do that (Browser and Widget are other opstion).

What I need to do is a samll application which pops-up after every call and asks the user if he wants to save(assign) this conversation (only the duration in minutes of the phone call is important) in his time-tracking database. He can click NO, but after it, he can start my application and see all unassigned phone calls and still he can assign them in the time-tracking db. This should happen offline and than be synchronized with the server via online connection.

My question now:
What APIs are to be used, for handling with the phone-calls?
Are there some downsides in this kind of application, which I newby can not see at first?
What about the different devices?

Thanks for any information you share with me, to help me avoid common newby mistakes!
Thnaks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should definitely be doable, look at the [PhoneListener](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.2.1api/net/rim/blackberry/api/phone/PhoneListener.html) interface to check when the phone call disconnects.  What I would do is write the application as a system module, that will run in the background on startup.  You can use an alternate entry point so that when the user clicks on your icon the application will create a GUI.

Edit: By the way BlackBerry uses an extended version of J2ME.  You can ignore all the RIM specific extensions if you want and develop an app that will (theoretically) work on any J2ME device but you won't be able to use a lot of nice features including the PhoneListener interface.  I doubt you'll be able to create this specific application with J2ME alone.

Comment: Thanks for this comment! very useful.        In the PhoneListener Interface I found this comment: ###Signed: This element is only accessible by signed clients### Is this any commercial version, do I need any spcial licenses for it?